# Crop excess white space from scanned TIFF

Tags: c#, .net, tiff

I have documents that are being scanned that are less than 8.5 x 11.  They are probably more like 8.5 x 5.  The scanners being used are centering the documents vertically and still making 8.5 x 11 TIFFs.  I'm looking for a way to automatically remove the white space from the top and bottom of the images.  If the image's orientation is changed, there could potentially be excess white space on all 4 sides of the image.  Assume there is no setting on the scanner to prevent it from doing this.

**tl;dr**
Does anyone know of a decent TIFF library that can auto crop images?

Comment: a quick google on tiff library with auto crop gives a bunch of results that look to be relevant.

Comment: Once it is loaded into the .NET Bitmap class, it doesn't matter what the original image format was.  I would just look for general .NET autocropping techniques.

Comment: @Brian When I google ".net tiff library with auto crop" I get one legitimate result and 9 link farms.

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily need a "tiff library" to do this.  you could do it in c#, something like this...

- convert the tiff to a bitmap
- inspect the bitmap, pixel by pixel to determine where the whitespace starts/ends
- once you know the pixel coordinates of the surrounding whitespace, you can then crop the bitmap image
- save the new image

Reference these pages for more information:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.getpixel%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.croppedbitmap%28v=vs.85%29.aspx